# GROUP BY subtype duplicate values in query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
create or replace type album_type as object 
(albumTitle         varchar(50),
 albumPlaytime      number(3), -- minutes
 albumReleaseDate   date, 
 albumGenre         varchar(15),
 albumPrice         number(9,2),
 albumTracks        number(2),
member function discountPrice return number)
 return integer)
not instantiable not final 
/
create or replace type disk_type under album_type 
( mediaType         varchar(10),
 diskNum            number(2), -- number of disks
 diskUsedPrice      number(9,2),
 diskDeliveryCost   number(9,2), 
overriding member function discountPrice return number)
/
create or replace type mp3_type under album_type
(downloadSize   number, -- size in MB
 overriding member function discountPrice return number)

insert into albums values (
    disk_type (
       'The Essential Bob Dylan', 99,'8-Jul-2016','Pop', 37.00, 32, 
        artist_array_type(
            artist_type('Bob Dylan','Composer'),             
            artist_type ('Bob Dylan','Vocals')),         
        review_table_type (             
            review_type ('shawn','24-jul-2018','wife loved it!', 5
    ),      review_type ('reuben','2-aug-2019','great compilation of some of his most known songs', 5)),
    'Vinyl', 2
, null
, 11.00)
        )
```

trying to execute following code:

```
SELECT t1.albumTitle ,  t2.artistName 
FROM albums t1, TABLE(t1.albumArtists ) t2  
WHERE  value(t1) IS OF (mp3_type) GROUP BY t1.albumTitle , t2.artistName  ORDER BY t1.albumTitle;
```

But the problem is that the resulted output has duplicated values

[the resulted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp9TR.png)

the following code:

```
SELECT t1.albumTitle 
FROM albums t1, TABLE(t1.albumArtists ) t2  
WHERE  value(t1) IS OF (mp3_type) GROUP BY t1.albumTitle  ORDER BY t1.albumTitle;
```

has no duplicated values

But no output subtype  t2.artistName

trying to execute following code:

```
SELECT t1.albumTitle ,  t2.artistName 
FROM albums t1, TABLE(t1.albumArtists ) t2  
WHERE  value(t1) IS OF (mp3_type) GROUP BY t1.albumTitle , t2.artistName  ORDER BY t1.albumTitle;
```

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using objects and not tables here? Seems like you could do with 3, maybe 4 tables with relevant primary and foreign keys. It would be a heck of a lot easier to query, add data, etc.

Comment: I agree, tables are  a lot easier to query in PL/SQL . But I took the  problem  as object programming.....

Comment: So this is a learning exercise? If so, please never do this for real! There are times when objects are useful in Oracle, but storing data is easier if you use tables not objects! You'll have far fewer maintenance headaches for a start! *{:-)

Comment: It is a uni assignment

Comment: Blooming universities - teaching everyone to use objects in tables as if that's a thing you should ever do in real life (you should not!)